# Unable to create a Sandbox Paypal account

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to this, so pardon if the question looks silly. I want to integrate **Paypal** in my project, which is made in codeigniter. For that I need a `personal account` in **Paypal**. While creating a personal account in `developer.paypal.com`. I have filled following information in the form-

```
Country: United States
Account Type: Personal
Email: vish@test.com
password: 12345678
PayPal balance: 500000
Bank verified account: No
Select payment card: PayPal
Credit card type: Visa
```

But When I click on **Create Account**, it is showing error as

```
We're sorry but something went wrong.Please delete this account and try again.
```

Can anyone guide to right path? Any positive suggestion or reply is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Create PayPal live account and log in to developer.paypal.com with live live account credentials. Generate test business and personal account ids. Use those ids for testing.

Comment: @Tsimtsum I've created a live PayPal account, and with it's credentials I'm logging into developer.paypal.com.

Comment: When I checked the account profile, it is showing Account Status as Unverified. Is this because I have entered a dummy **email** while creating personal account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer. The balance I set was to high as mentioned [here](http://believeinmiraclesx.wordpress.com/2013/03/15/paypal-sandbox-were-sorry-but-something-went-wrong-please-delete-this-account-and-try-again/), along with the factor Password should have special character like (!@#$%&*), number(s) and at least 1 capital letter. And it worked for me.